# How to update asp.net core version in dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I'm building a docker container as a step in Azure DevOps pipeline and using the provided build pools. When I try to run the container, I get the error below. I understand I need to update the asp.net version as I build the container, and I'm looking for a command line that I can add to my Dockerfile to do so.

I've found a number of places to download the correct version but have not found a good way to put the download & install as a command in a docker file.

My Dockerfile is quite simple and is based on Windows 1803.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-sac2016 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY SampleMvcApp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Meta-Analytics.dll"]
```

A snippet from the error I get is below:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.2.5' was not found.

The following versions are installed:
2.2.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as the project was upgraded at some point, but did not follow all of the migration options.

Support for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` has been deprecated in version 2.1. You should replace it by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and you should not be specifying a version.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2#migrate for details, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.2